# How to make an NSFetchRequest which asks for objects that have a specific firstname?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

For example, I have a Managed Object Model with an Entity called "Friends", and a friend has a firstName. I want to get all friends where the firstName is equal to "George". How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Friends" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 

[request setEntity:entityDescription]; 

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == 'George'"]]; 
NSError *error = nil; 
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```